# Custom functions in emacs?

Tags: functions

I'm finding I run `C-x C-f` and then:

```
/ssh:$user@$host|sudo:$host:/
```

Where `$host` is a device IP.

I'm relatively new to emacs, I want to create a custom function that accepts values for `$host` and `$user`.

How can I do this?

Comment: [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Writing-Defuns.html) should prove helpful.

Comment: If you access the same locations over ssh from time to time, you may wish to set up an `.authinfo` or `.netrc` to login automatically.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22974359/2112489

Comment: I didn't realize at first but I can actually just hit up after `C-x C-f` to use my last used connection.